# How to redirect to other page when session expired and the PC wakeup from sleep mode - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a problem with the expire session, I have a dynamic action which redirect the users to a "Your session has expired!" page, this work without problem but if the session expired when the PC is on sleep mode, the dynamic action won't active until the user log in the PC, but when this happend, the dynamic action won't run correctly and only show the apex notification: "your session is expired" instead redirection, there is a way fix this?

Like using JS which run script, when show the apex notification with 'Your session is expired' then user is redirect to other page.

[The apex notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmquK.png)

Comment: Could you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If about the redirection then:
      apex.navigation.redirect("f?p=100:10:0:");

Answer (score 0):

Under Shared Components -> Security -> Session Management, you'll find the Maximum Session Idle Time in Seconds and Session Idle Timeout URL

[oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_wrkspc002.htm#CIHGBGJF)

Comment: I already set a URL for this and work under normal circunstance (when the PC is active) but the problem is when PC is on sleep mode and the session expire there, when the PC wake up, the redirection don't work and only show a notification about your expired session.